# filter by intersection of lists

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Object-Class that has a ManyToManyRelation to `groups`. Now I want to get all the objects from that class where at least one group of the user is in the groups attribute of the Class.

Something like:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(groups hasIntersectionWith request.user.groups.all())
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(groups__user=request.user)
```

this will return a `MyClass` if there is at least one `Group` in common with the `Group`s of the `request.user`.

Comment: @progNewbie: yes, so: `MyClass.objects.filter(groups__user=request.user).distinct()`.